# How to divide the YML file for Serverless AWS

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless

I need to divide my yml file in more files, because is very big... It would be nice if I can invoke other file that contains my custom datas, another file for my resources, another file for my functions...

How can I make this?

Answer (score 0):

You can reference other YML files using the `${file}` notation inside your serverless YML file.
https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#reference-variables-in-other-files

This way you can split you big YML file in multiple smaller files, but be careful because it couldn't be an easy task ;)